# How do I mock and test chained function with jest?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, mocking, react-testing-library

I have this function chain in my components useEffect hook.
I set the response/data to my component state so I can render the data in my component.

```
client
  .items()
  .type("client")
  .toObservable()
  .subscribe(response => {
    setState(response)
  })
```

How do I mock this function and call it before the component renders in my test? I'm using testing-library/react.

the response is
`{items: [{},...]}, somethingElse: {}`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use [mockFn.mockReturnThis()](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockreturnthis) to do this.

`client.ts`, emulate a real third-party module

```js
const client = {
  items: () => {
    return client;
  },
  type: (name: string) => {
    return client;
  },
  toObservable: () => {
    return client;
  },
  subscribe: handler => {
    handler();
    return client;
  }
};

export { client };
```

Use `client.ts` module in react component:

```js
class Component {
  private props;
  constructor(props) {
    this.props = props;
  }
  public componentDidMount() {
    this.props.client
      .items()
      .type('client')
      .toObservable()
      .subscribe(response => {
        this.setState(response);
      });
  }
  private setState(state) {
    console.log(state);
  }
}

export { Component };
```

Unit test, mock chain method of the real `client.ts` module, inject the mocked `client` module into your component.

```js
import { Component } from './';

const mockClient = {
  items: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  type: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  toObservable: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  subscribe: jest.fn().mockReturnThis()
};

const mockProps = {
  client: mockClient
};

const component = new Component(mockProps);

describe('Component', () => {
  describe('#componentDidMount', () => {
    it('should mount the component and set state correctly', () => {
      const mockedResponse = { items: [{}], somethingElse: {} };
      mockClient.subscribe.mockImplementationOnce(handler => handler(mockedResponse));
      // tslint:disable-next-line: no-string-literal
      component['setState'] = jest.fn();
      component.componentDidMount();
      expect(mockClient.items().type).toBeCalledWith('client');
      // tslint:disable-next-line: no-string-literal
      expect(component['setState']).toBeCalledWith(mockedResponse);
    });
  });
});
```

Unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/mock-function/57719741/index.spec.ts
  Component
    #componentDidMount
      ✓ should mount the component and set state correctly (6ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.542s, estimated 2s
```